# does pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.12 support multiple headers?

Tags: groovy, pact, pact-jvm

When there are multiple headers in the interaction, pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.12 version 3.5.25 throws an exception when I run `mvn pact:verify` to verify the contract at the provider side

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot set property 'text' on null object
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.setProperty (NullObject.java:80)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty (InvokerHelper.java:197)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty (ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:484)
at au.com.dius.pact.provider.reporters.JsonReporter.finaliseReport (JsonReporter.groovy:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod (IndyInterface.java:232)
at au.com.dius.pact.provider.ProviderVerifier$_finialiseReports_closure32.doCall (ProviderVerifier.groovy:367)
```

My interaction is

```
"interactions": [
    {
      "description": "Consumer interaction of Put Person Algorithm",
      "request": {
        "method": "PUT",
        "path": "model/v0/algorithm/person",
        "headers": {
          "Authorization": "Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "query": {
          "crn": [
            "TENANT_NAME"
          ]
        },
        "body": {
          "standardizers": {},
          "encryption": {},
          "entity_types": {},
          "locale": "en_us"
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      },
      "providerStates": [
        {
          "name": "B Put Person Algorithm"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

If I remove "Content-Type": "application/json" from the request headers, this error will be gone. Is this a bug in the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely it supports multiple headers. It may be a big with that specific version or some other artifact of the test process. Could you please file a bug report and ideally a reproducible example?

Worth checking you're on the latest version of the maven plugin also.